# Will these commands return the same output on different Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line, monitoring

I am writing a monitoring script. I am running it on a specific machine, and it works. It is planned to be ran on several Linux machines, not bound to a single distribution.

Here are the commands and the related treatments I do : 
1) CPU usage :

```
top -bn 2 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1"%"}'
92%
93%
```

I log both values.

2) RAM usage

```
free -m

_____total        used        free      shared buff/cache   available <br>
 Mem 3791        1183         875          16        1732        2326 <br>
 Swap 3071           0        3071
```

Log both memory and swap used/total

3) Disk usage :

```
df
```

(only keeping columns 2 and 3, which are respectively total number of 1024 bits blocks, and used blocks) :

```
 1K_blocks used_blocks
 27740944 1996820
  1931168       0
  1941352       0
  1941352   16904
  1941352       0
   508588  151576
   388272       0
```

I compare both column sums to get overall disk space.

4) Uptime :

```
PS C:\> invoke-sshcommand -ComputerName $ip {uptime}
09:39:01 up 13 days, 21:37,  1 user,  load average: 0,00, 0,01, 0,05
```

Cut this string and log usefull data.

**Will these commands give the exact same form of output regardless of the Linux distribution ?**
More generally, would a command + data treatment be still valid on any distribution ?

Comment: If you had a list of *specific* distributions, this might be helpfully answerable, but as it stands the (useless) answer is "no".

Comment: Probably not these commands.  Stick with [POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and you'll be fine (usually).  Not sure that all of the commands you want are specified by POSIX, though.

Comment: Sad there is no env. variables in Unix. Is there a way to format outputs so they match POSIX ?    
@Michael Homer I don't know what distributions the script will be used on as the server list will not be defined by myself.

Comment: What do you mean by `there is no env. variables in Unix`? And the data you quoted also available from `/proc` pseudofiles if you'll always on Linux, so you can read them directly rather than relying on "standard" programs.

Comment: it's curious to me that you're not keeping the mountpoints associated with the used/free space. Also, look into the -P flag for 'df'.

Comment: You might help yourself by attempting to identify distributions and/or releases in order to tailor your subsequent commands, as needed.

Comment: there is no need to pipe data into `grep` then `sed` then `awk`.  awk can do everything that grep and sed can do and a whole lot more.  e.g. `top -bn 2 | awk '/Cpu\(s\)/ {print 100 - $8"%"}'`

Answer (score 1):

> Will these commands give the exact same form of output regardless of the Linux distribution ?

**Perhaps, but you cannot be sure of it.**

There are hundreds of Linux distributions ([DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com) counts 280 of them) and you cannot have the guarantee that one script written for one will work - or will *continue* to work - on another, especially if it uses some non-POSIX option or flag.

What should you do, instead of relying on output from commands, is to take the data directly from the `/proc` pseudo filesystem.

Comment: Thx for answer. I run my tests of a CentOS 7 machine and I think the other Linux distributions the script will run on are also 'common' ones (exept maybe for web servers). So I assume that if it works for CentOS, it should work of these aswell. My main concern is that if one of the 4 commands returns a differently formated output that  I expect in my script, it will surely screw the related data up.